# Authentication using AES

Tags: aes, authentication, symmetric, mac

I need to implement an authentication mechanism in an embedded environment which does not support floating point operations but has an AES accelerator module which allows for encyption/decryption operations.

Currently, I'm thinking of using the following approach:

1. Compute the ciphertext of the message using a secret key k1.
2. In parallel compute the ciphertext of the same message using secret key k2(k1 $\neq$ k2). Upon the encryption of each block the current block is XOR-ed with the previous so that the length of the authentication code is always equal to the size of a block (i.e. 128 bits).
3. The message to be sent is obtained by concatenating the ciphertext with the authentication code.

Is this approach secure?

Comment: What modes of encryption does the accelerator use? You could likely use [CBC-MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBC-MAC).

Comment: @mikeazo 128-bit CBC

Comment: What block cipher mode are you using? Why don't you just use [CMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMAC) as the MAC? (CBC-MAC is secure only with fixed length messages.)

Comment: P.S., you should definitely [read this if you want to use CBC-MAC](http://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2013/02/why-i-hate-cbc-mac.html). It goes along with otus's comment.

Comment: Does the accelerator give you direct access to the round function?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**TL;DR**
No, the approach is not secure. Use a standard like [CMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMAC) instead. Or even better, check your AES accelerator module to see if it supports any [AEAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) modes of encryption like [GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode), [CCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCM_mode), [EAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAX_mode).

**Long Version**

In order for a [message authentication code (MAC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) to be secure, an adversary with oracle access to the MAC (basically this means the adversary can send arbitrary messages to a black-box that will compute the MAC tag), should not be able to forge a MAC (i.e., construct a valid MAC for something that the black box never computed a MAC for).

I am going to ignore step 1 for now since that is the confidentiality part and has no impact on the authentication part. Also, I'm assuming you are using AES-CBC with a 128-bit key based on [your comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27339/authentication-using-aes#comment63925_27339).

So the proposal is to encrypt the plaintext with a key $k_2$, then XOR all the blocks together to get a MAC tag. Let's assume that a static IV of all 0's is used for the MAC.

For a two block message, say $m_1,m_2$, the MAC would be $MAC_1 = E_{k_2}(m_1)\oplus E_{k_2}(E_{k_2}(m_1)\oplus m_2)$. I could also ask the oracle for the MAC of $m_1$ by itself, which would be $MAC_2 = E_{k_2}(m_1)$.

Notice now that $MAC_1\oplus MAC_2$ is a valid MAC for the message $E_{k_2}(m_1)\oplus m_2$, but I never asked the black box for that MAC. So that would be a break.

How useful is this? Well, since the attacker controls $m_1$ and $m_2$, and can get $E_{k_2}(m_1)$ before choosing $m_2$, the attacker can make $E_{k_2}(m_1)\oplus m_2$ anything she wants by setting $m_2$ appropriately. Therefore, the attacker can ask for two MACs on non-malicious looking messages (likely they will look random), but get a MAC on a chosen message.

So, no, your approach is not secure.

Comment: If it's not available it would be a good idea to implement EAX on top of the accelerator. You'd only need CMAC (or even CBC-MAC, as CMAC relies on CBC-MAC) to implement it. Then you can switch when it becomes available.